# Iterar for com duas variáveis

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
def hasPalin(string):
    begin = 0
    end = len(string)-1
    result = ""
    while(begin < len(string)/2):
        if (string[begin] == string[end]):
            result += string[begin]
        else:
            break
        begin += 1
        end -= 1
    return result
```

Seria possível transformar esse **while** em um **for**? Ou seja, iterar sobre 2 variáveis, sendo uma um incremento, e outra um decremento.

Não testei, mas tenho quase certeza que é possível fazer isso em java, onde eu incremento uma variável, enquanto decremento outra.

Comment: Poderia dizer qual é o objetivo dessa função?

Comment: @Sidon Ela verifica se o inicio de uma string é igual ao final, tipo um sub palíndromo, sendo input: abcqwertbca, o output seria: abc. Mas a minha dúvida maior é se é possível fazer um for nessas características.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim dá para iterar com duas variáveis no python com `for`. Para isso pode usar a função `zip` que devolve um tuplo assim:

```
for var1, var2 in zip(colecao1, colecao2):
```

O que no seu caso ficava algo como:

```
tam = len(string)

for begin, end in zip(range(0,tam), range(tam-1,-1,-1)):
```

Em que o primeiro `range` constrói os valores crescentes e o segundo `range` constrói os valores decrescentes.

Se a ideia do algoritmo era verificar um sub-palíndromo, e aproveitando a sua lógica pode fazer:

```
def hasPalin(string):
    result = ""
    tam = int(len(string)/2)

    #Primeiro range de 0 até metade e o segundo do fim até metade
    for begin, end in zip(range(0,tam), range(len(string)-1,tam-1,-1)): 
        if string[begin] == string[end]:
            result += string[begin]
        else:
            return result #devolver o subpalíndromo. É diferente logo pode parar aqui

    return string #se chegou aqui a frase é totalmente um palíndromo e devolve o original

print(hasPalin("casaca")) #""
print(hasPalin("osctso")) #"os"
print(hasPalin("abcddcba")) #"abcddcba"
```

Comment: Tente com uma string grande que seja totalmente palindromo, como por exemplo: `ataxxxxxxxxxata`, o resulstado teria q ser a string original, correto? Pela logica isso aconteceria no codigo da sua resposta?

Comment: @Sidon Isso é de facto uma pergunta interessante. A qual eu não sei qual era a intenção do autor. Mas na sua ótica deveria retornar apenas a parte que é palíndromo quando é parcial e o texto todo original quando é totalmente um palíndromo ?

Comment: Se vc testar seu codigo com `aaddaa` ele vai ficar confuso. :-)

Comment: Mas vc tem razão, é preciso saber qual é a real intenção do autor, mas é  muito estranho um sub-palindromo em um palindromo. Por exemplo, o que seria um sub em uma string assim: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`? e, ainda mais intrigante, em `ada`

Comment: @Sidon Sim eu até eu acho que o que está a dizer faz até sentido, embora não seja clara a intenção do autor, ou até se ele pensou nisso! Mas acho que vou alterar o código para contemplar esse pormenor também.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela contribuição de vocês, eu não pensei nesses casos mesmo. Esbarrei nesse problema em algum site para treinar programação e essa dúvida do for ficou na minha cabeça, mas você já esclareceram ela, que era a razão principal. Agora, o resto deixo por conta de vocês, hehe.

Answer (score 2):

Quando cheguei com o zip, o Isac ja tinha respondido, mas mesmo assim vou tentar fazer uma contribuição com uma forma um pouco mais pythonica para a função que vc deseja:

```
def haspalin(_str):
    p=''
    for i in range(len(_str)-1):
        if _str[i] != _str[::-1][i]:
            return p 
        else:
            p+=_str[i]
    return _str        

print(haspalin('atabcdefata'))
ata
print(haspalin('ataxxxxxxxxxata'))
ataxxxxxxxxxata
```

> Editada, Explicação:

`_str[::-1][i]:` Inverte a string, então é feita uma iteração na string original comparando através do ídice `i` do loop for cada caracter da string original com o caracter do indice correspondente na string invertida, se forem iguais, ele é adicionado à variável `p`, quando for encontrado o primeiro caracterer não correspondente, a função é 'abortada', retornando a variável `p`.

[Veja rodando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/KDnV/1)